# How do I sort on Count_Orders in MySQL in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

For an assignment I need to get an output giving the product categories ordered at least 5 or more times, and this with the most ordered category first.

```
SELECT P.category,count(O.order_id)AS COUNT_Orders
FROM Orders O,Product P
WHERE O.product_id = P.product_id
GROUP BY Category
HAVING COUNT(*)>=5
```

This is currently my query, but I can't find a way to use Order by on `COUNT_Orders` without getting an error in MySQL.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: How did you add `Order by` in your query? It should be added just at the end `..HAVING COUNT(*)>=5 Order by COUNT_Orders`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT P.category, count(O.order_id) as COUNT_Orders
FROM Orders O JOIN
     Product P
     ON O.product_id = P.product_id
GROUP BY Category
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5 
ORDER BY COUNT_Orders;
```

In addition to adding the `ORDER BY` clause, this version uses proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.